# HTML Video: deliver file in chunks (stream?) not in a single file

Tags: video-streaming, html5-video

I would like to deliver a video from a website in chunks. What I want to achieve is, that neither in the code nor in the network panel the user can see the URL to the video file to make prevent the possibility to download it as one file.

As an example, all the videos here are deliverd in as multiple .ts files: https://tvthek.orf.at/history/Frauen-in-Politik-und-Geschichte/13557870/Johanna-Dohnal-Emanze-mit-Stolz/13904446

How can I create such .ts chunks from a .mp4 file and how do I get the html video tag to accept these chunks as source?

Answer (score 0):

The example you posted that uses ts chunks is in a format called HLS. It is a very common format, but was not developed to prevent people from saving a copy of the video. Many tools like ffmpeg can download and reassemble the chunks into a single file.

Comment: Thanks for the info. It still makes it much more effort to download the video (I know there are scripts for that, but still). Do you know any ressources on how to create it and use it with the HTML video element?

Comment: "It still makes it much more effort" <= not for people who know what HLS is. "Do you know any ressources" Stackoverflow and the internet are full of resource for HLS. you can use google to find them.